# Retrieving heart rate data from Android watch face service

Tags: service, sensors, wear-os, watch

Does anyone have links to sample code that shows how to set up heart sensor data retrieval directly from **CanvasWatchFaceService** or **CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine** ?

(Most of the code I've seen thus far perform sensor data retrieval from a wearable's **Activity** class, but not from a watch face environment.)

I've tried setting things up this way:

```
private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine implements SensorEventListener {
    ...
    ... // implement interface methods
}
```

But I keep getting a null object for my sensor.

My manifest contains:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you requested `android.permission.BODY_SENSORS` permission in your both mobile and wearable `AndroidManifest`.

Also, look into the logcat of your wearable device and `grep` for `android.permission.BODY_SENSORS`.

Comment: Thnx. Yes I've added that permission to the mobile project also, but to no avail; I still get a null sensor object. I'm using a Moto360 device - could **that** be the problem? AFAYK, does Moto360 block access to the heart rate sensor?

Comment: Did you look into the logcat and grep for the BODY_SENSORS? Check if you get the permission.

Comment: Just sharing: I followed this solution but failed in the first hour. I was so mad and restarted the watch. Then the problem solved....